# Use "net use" command using the account other than Administrator

Tags: windows

I could use "net use" command at windows successfully using both Administrator and other account. But I can't use other account to go to " \\IPAddress\c$ password /User:username". This could be done using Administrator account.

Does anyone know what's the setting at the server side that could solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Permissions maybe? I think it should be a double backslash for computer ip - \\ip\c$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are issuing the command `net use \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\c$` you are attempting to connect to a special share known as the [Administrative share](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share)

To connect to that share, the person requesting the connection needs to be in admin group on the remote computer.

You options are

1. Add the local non-admin users into the admin group on the remote server (less desirable)
2. You *might* be able to grant the local user explicit permissions on the remote C$ share but I've never tried that.
3. Provide alternate credentials for the net use command

   net use \xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\c$ MySecurePassw0rd /user:RemoteComputerName\RemoteUser

net use /?

```
The syntax of this command is:

NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

Comment: Actually I tried to add the account to Administrators group. I went to "Local Users and Groups--groups" add the account to Administrators. This does not help. Also when I tried to use alternate credentials it prompts for password. After I entered the correct username/password. It says \\IPAddress\c$ not accessible. You might not have permission to use network resource.

Comment: This problem has been solvehttp://support.microsoft.com/kb/942817